# Reading a text file in unity and then applying the data in the text file to a game object in order to shown 3D rotations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need the necessary code to read a text file into Unity, and then use the euler angle values from the text file to show rotations in a 3D space. An example of the text file data is 111.81  -2.28  105.00     48.18  22.11  100.69. The first three numbers are the x,y, and z of the a thigh and the last three numbers are the x, y, and z of a hip. I need this data to be represented in a 3D space. The coding language is C#.

Comment: Welcome to [so], please take some time to read the [ask] section of the help pages.

Comment: So what have you tried? StackOverflow is for asking specific questions about a specific issue with a specific implementation ... Not for describing a vague use-case and expect a full working tool implementation as answer ....

Answer (score -1):

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path); 
Debug.Log(reader.ReadToEnd());
reader.Close();
```

store this text in a string then after every space you can get each values.